# Change Jersey default for HEAD requests

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

By default Jersey handles `HEAD` requests using the `GET` resource:

> By default the JAX-RS runtime will automatically support the methods HEAD and OPTIONS, if not explicitly implemented. For HEAD the runtime will invoke the implemented GET method (if present) and ignore the response entity (if set).

[Chapter 3. JAX-RS Application, Resources and Sub-Resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2083)

Is it possible to change this default?

Comment: To what do you want to change it? Do you want to forbid HEAD requests or call some other method when a HEAD request is made.

Comment: Currently I have HEAD implemented like @gba suggested and I just return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a way to change it globally, however, you can implement a method with @HEAD annotation and it will be called instead of the @GET annotated method.

```
@GET
@Path("a/b")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getSomething() {
 .....
}

@HEAD
@Path("a/b")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response headSomething() {
 .....
}
```

when firing a HEAD request to a/b, headSomething method will be called.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have right now. I wanted to know if there was a way to change  that default. Long term I think I'll go with a filter if changing the default is not possible.